# bundle exec rake resque：work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I want install dradis in my ubuntu 17.10 server.But,When I runing bundle exec rake resque:work.Command can not be executed.Before I never use ruby，please help me.Thanks

And I want update my bundler version,After I runing  `gem install bundler` ，but the bundler still == 1.15.1，very confused.

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/dradis-ce/bin# bundle exec rake resque：work --trace
(in /opt/dradis-ce)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'resque：work' (see --tasks)
/opt/dradis-ce/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:59:in `[]'
/opt/dradis-ce/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:159:in `invoke_task'
/opt/dradis-ce/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/opt/dradis-ce/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/opt/dradis-ce/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/opt/dradis-ce/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/opt/dradis-ce/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/opt/dradis-ce/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/opt/dradis-ce/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/dradis-ce/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
rake:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
The latest bundler is 1.16.1, but you are currently running 1.15.1.
To update, run `gem install bundler`
root@ubuntu:/opt/dradis-ce/bin#
```

Comment: Have you followed this steps properly https://dradisframework.com/ce/documentation/install_kali.html

Comment: Try to follow this https://github.com/dradis/dradis-ce/

Comment: There's a space between `:` and `work`, might that be it?